# Looping Scroll View in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to create a scroll view that keeps on repeating its elements. Let's say it has 10 elements, so after the 10th element, the 1st element would show up and so on, infinitely.

**NOTE:** I'm not talking about infinite scrolling to load more elements. Just a cyclic structure in scroll view.

The solution that came to my mind is that a normal scroll view with those 10 elements, and every time I reach the end and invoke `onEndReached`, it will append those 10 elements ahead of it and give it an illusion that it actually is cyclic or looping nature. Only problem is that it doesn't sound efficient, like, storing duplicate elements on and on, every time you reach the end, into the data array. Is there any better solution possible?

Comment: how about this one? **https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper**

Comment: Your solution is not that costly and it is probably the best way. Interface-wise I think it's kind of confusing for the user and a carousel might be more intuitive but if you want it the best bet would probably be to "append" new Views by manipulating the state.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called **react-native-snap-carousel** [here](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel) in the GitHub that represents a rich carousel. Maybe you can get better ideas.

Another issues in the solution that you mentioned is when you go to the first of the scroll view, then duplication won't solve any problem.

**EDIT 1:**

Another library is [**react-native-swiper**](https://github.com/leecade/react-native-swiper).

Comment: I've checked out that library, not solving my particular issue for some reason. Also the first of the scroll won't be a problem for my use-case.